# Scrypto Importing Structs from other folder

Tags: rust, scrypto, radix-dlt

In Scrypto, I have folder structure like:

```
src/
├── lib.rs
├── script.rs
├── custom_types
│   └── type.rs
```

In `type.rs`, I have the following defined:

```rust
use sbor::*;

#[derive(TypeId, Encode, Decode, Describe)]
pub struct Date {
    year: u8,
    day: u8,
    month: u8,
}
```

I want to be able to use the `Date` struct in `script.rs` how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Organize files like:

```
src/
├── lib.rs
├── script.rs
├── custom_types
│   └── type.rs
│   └── mod.rs
```

`mod.rs`:

```rust
pub mod type;
```

Add the following to `script.rs`:

```rust
use super::custom_types::type::Date;

...
```

Finally, add the following to `lib.rs`

```rust
mod datatypes;
```